# Rmarkdown latex output: issue with sapply

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

See `reprex1` and `reprex2` below. `lapply` runs but with `sapply` there's a `"` added to the beginning of line 87 in .tex file, breaking it.

Ideas?

```
---
title: "reprex"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

```
{r reprex1, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

species = c("Human", "Droid")

lapply(species, function(x){
  
  starwars %>%
    select(name, birth_year) %>%
    kable() %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE, latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
})
```

```
{r reprex2, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

species = c("Human", "Droid")

sapply(species, function(x){
  
  starwars %>%
    select(name, birth_year) %>%
    kable() %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE, latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you might want to add a line in your function that actually does something with the variable x, such as filtering, otherwise you are just returning twice the same output.

`sapply(x, f, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)` is the same as `lapply(x, f)`, so you could compare the output of the `sapply` statement below with `simplify = TRUE` vs. `simplify = FALSE`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

species = c("Human", "Droid")

str(sapply(species, function(x){
    starwars %>%
        dplyr::filter(species == x) %>%
        select(name, birth_year) %>%
        kable() %>%
        kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE, latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
        row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
}, simplify = FALSE)[[1]])
#>  'kableExtra' chr "<table class=\"table\" style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">\n <thead>\n  <tr>\n   <th style=\"text"| __truncated__
#>  - attr(*, "format")= chr "html"

str(sapply(species, function(x){
    starwars %>%
        dplyr::filter(species == x) %>%
        select(name, birth_year) %>%
        kable() %>%
        kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE, latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
        row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
}, simplify = TRUE)[[1]])
#>  chr "<table class=\"table\" style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">\n <thead>\n  <tr>\n   <th style=\"text"| __truncated__
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
`lapply` returns a list (with the class `c("kableExtra", "knitr_kable")`, with the attribute `attr(*, "format")= chr "html")`), while `sapply` returns a vector of characters with `attr(*, "names")= chr "Human"`.